React Audio Player Change current time of Audio
I'm working on a custom audio player in React with Bootstrap, and I want to make it possible to fast forward or rewind the playback by 5 seconds.
I also want to be able to change the time using a slider.
This somehow does not work.
CURRENTLY the code behaves in such a way that if I fast forward or rewind 5 seconds the MP-3 starts again.
App.js
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "./index.scss";
import { Button, Card, Container, ProgressBar } from "react-bootstrap";

import AudioPlayer from "./components/AudioPlayer";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container>
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <Card>
          <Card.Header> Audio </Card.Header>
          <Card.Body>
            <AudioPlayer
              audioSrc="/assets/Test_ogg_mp3_48kbps.wav.ogg"
              name="Lehrpfad Audio 1"
            />
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}


AudioPlayer
import React from "react";
import { Button, ProgressBar, InputGroup, FormControl } from "react-bootstrap";
import {
  PlayCircleFill,
  PauseCircleFill,
  VolumeMuteFill,
  VolumeDownFill,
  VolumeUpFill,
} from "react-bootstrap-icons";

class AudioPlayer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.audioRef = React.createRef();
    this.audioSrc = props.audioSrc;

    this.state = {
      isPlaying: false,
      currentTime: 0,
      volume: 1, // Range between 0 and 1
      progress: 0,
    };
  }

  togglePlayPause() {
    const { isPlaying } = this.state;
    const audio = this.audioRef.current;
    if (isPlaying) {
      audio.pause();
    } else {
      audio.play();
    }
    this.setState({ isPlaying: !isPlaying });
  }

  handleTimeUpdate() {
    const audio = this.audioRef.current;
    if (audio && !isNaN(audio.duration)) {
      const progressPercentage = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100;
      this.setState({ progress: progressPercentage });
      if (progressPercentage >= 100) {
        this.setState({ isPlaying: false, progress: 0 });
      }
    }
  }

  getVolumeIcon() {
    const { volume } = this.state;
    if (volume <= 0) {
      return <VolumeMuteFill />;
    } else if (volume > 0 && volume <= 0.5) {
      return <VolumeDownFill />;
    } else {
      return <VolumeUpFill />;
    }
  }

  handleVolumeChange(e) {
    const newVolume = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ volume: newVolume });
    if (this.audioRef.current) {
      this.audioRef.current.volume = newVolume;
    }
  }

  skipTime(seconds) {
    const player = document.getElementById("Player");
    if (player && !isNaN(player.currentTime)) {
      player.currentTime += seconds;
      this.setState();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { isPlaying, progress, volume } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container mt-5 audio-player">
        <audio
          id="Player"
          ref={this.audioRef}
          src={this.audioSrc} // Ersetze dies durch den Pfad zu deiner Audiodatei
          onTimeUpdate={this.handleTimeUpdate.bind(this)}
          onEnded={() => this.setState({ isPlaying: false })}
        />
        <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.skipTime(-5)}>
            {" "}
            -5s{" "}
          </Button>
          <Button
            variant="primary"
            onClick={this.togglePlayPause.bind(this)}
            className="mx-2"
          >
            {isPlaying ? <PauseCircleFill /> : <PlayCircleFill />}
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.skipTime(5)}>
            {" "}
            +5s{" "}
          </Button>
        </div>
        <ProgressBar
          striped
          variant="success"
          now={progress}
          label={`${Math.round(progress)}%`}
        />
        <InputGroup className="mt-3">
          <InputGroup.Text>{this.getVolumeIcon()}</InputGroup.Text>
          <FormControl
            type="range"
            min="0"
            max="1"
            step="0.1"
            value={volume}
            onChange={this.handleVolumeChange.bind(this)}
          />
        </InputGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AudioPlayer;



I tried everything that came into my mind but i was not sucessfull.
I did accept that a method would change the time.
codesandbox.io snippet

It would help if you'd create a runnable snippet in which we can debug your code. Either use codesandbox.io or a stack snippet for us to run your code. That being said, you're not using the ref to the audio element in the skipTime method and you're calling this.setState() when there is no state to be changed.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/testreact-8zsnft

The behavior you're describing isn't reproduced in your code snippet. Did the notes in my comment solve the problem or is it still there in your version?

somehow your notes solved the problem i do not know why thx - previously i also tried that but it did not work

import React from "react";
import { Button, ProgressBar, InputGroup, FormControl } from "react-bootstrap";
import {
  PlayCircleFill,
  PauseCircleFill,
  VolumeMuteFill,
  VolumeDownFill,
  VolumeUpFill,
  ArrowClockwise,
  ArrowCounterclockwise,
} from "react-bootstrap-icons";

class AudioPlayer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.audioRef = React.createRef();
    this.audioSrc = props.audioSrc;
    this.audioName = props.audioName || props.audioSrc;

    this.state = {
      isPlaying: false,
      currentTime: 0,
      volume: 1, // Range between 0 and 1
      progress: 0,
    };
  }

  togglePlayPause() {
    const { isPlaying } = this.state;
    const audio = this.audioRef.current;
    if (isPlaying) {
      audio.pause();
    } else {
      audio.play();
    }
    this.setState({ isPlaying: !isPlaying });
  }

  handleTimeUpdate() {
    const audio = this.audioRef.current;
    if (audio && !isNaN(audio.duration)) {
      const progressPercentage = (audio.currentTime / audio.duration) * 100;
      this.setState({ progress: progressPercentage });
      if (progressPercentage >= 100) {
        this.setState({ isPlaying: false, progress: 0 });
      }
    }
  }

  getVolumeIcon() {
    const { volume } = this.state;
    if (volume <= 0) {
      return <VolumeMuteFill />;
    } else if (volume > 0 && volume <= 0.5) {
      return <VolumeDownFill />;
    } else {
      return <VolumeUpFill />;
    }
  }

  handleVolumeChange(e) {
    const newVolume = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ volume: newVolume });
    if (this.audioRef.current) {
      this.audioRef.current.volume = newVolume;
    }
  }

  skipTime(seconds) {
    const audio = this.audioRef.current;
    if (audio && !isNaN(audio.currentTime)) {
      audio.currentTime += seconds;
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { isPlaying, progress, volume } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="audio-player">
        <p>{this.audioName}</p>
        <audio
          id="Player"
          ref={this.audioRef}
          src={this.audioSrc} // Ersetze dies durch den Pfad zu deiner Audiodatei
          onTimeUpdate={this.handleTimeUpdate.bind(this)}
          onEnded={() => this.setState({ isPlaying: false })}
          controls
        />
        <Button
          variant={isPlaying ? "danger" : "success"}
          onClick={this.togglePlayPause.bind(this)}
          className="playPauseBtn"
        >
          {isPlaying ? (
            <PauseCircleFill size={80} />
          ) : (
            <PlayCircleFill size={80} />
          )}
        </Button>
        <div className="audio-controls">
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.skipTime(-5)}>
            <ArrowCounterclockwise size={50} />
            -5sec
          </Button>

          <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.skipTime(5)}>
            <ArrowClockwise size={50} />
            +5sec
          </Button>
        </div>
        <ProgressBar
          striped
          variant="success"
          now={progress}
          label={`${Math.round(progress)}%`}
        />
        <InputGroup className="volume-input">
          <InputGroup.Text>{this.getVolumeIcon()}</InputGroup.Text>
          <FormControl
            type="range"
            min="0"
            max="1"
            step="0.1"
            value={volume}
            onChange={this.handleVolumeChange.bind(this)}
          />
        </InputGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AudioPlayer;


Please explain what you've changed to address the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I used the ref to the audio element in the skipTime method like Emiel Zuurbier said and it worked :D
